# Does Goldwasser-Micali only encrypts only 1-bit or multiple?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

I've read online that the Goldwasser-Micali scheme can only encrypt 1-bit then I read that in another pdf that that scheme can encrypt a message of multiple bits so I'm confused. Can anyone clarify please?

Comment: It should encrypt each bit separately! Could you provide the sources that confuse you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original scheme by Golwasser and Micali only encrypts one bit at a time. 
It is possible to extend it to encrypt multiple bits at the same time using an higher order residue.
Roughly one can encrypt up to $k$ bits using the $2^k$-th residue symbol.